# Build a PHP app that works like Siri for iOS

Tags: php

**Is it possible to build an application with PHP which automatically responds to each form submission?**

Like this:

[image: example]

So, for example, if the form submission were `$_POST['q'] = "hi"`, the output would be "Hello.."

Like using a `case` statement:

```
for case $_POST['q'] = "how do you do?"
echo "fine";

for case $_POST['q'] = "what's your name ? "
echo "ABC"
```

etc. etc.

***Can anyone help me out to build a function like that in PHP?***

what I am thinking of is: for a form submission, there should be a print/echo from arrays just like how Siri on iOS works...

Comment: A simple string comparison won't get you far. To actually try to understand what someone writing natural language wants/asks you need some pretty sophisticated algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement siri. The task is much sophisticated which includes Tokenization, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking, parsing, coreference resolution and much more programming. 
These links might help you.
[ai-class](https://www.ai-class.com/course/topic/2)
http://opennlp.apache.org/ 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/